# Charts.js graph not displaying

Tags: html, chart.js

I am trying to work a graph from a tutorial on charts.js. But the graph is not displaying when I run the html file.

I write the js code in a script as done in tutorial but it didn't work. Then it put the js code in a function but it didn't work either.

It would be nice if you can see whether is possible or better to put the js source in a script only or in a function. I have to display charts on top of a webpage displaying database tables.

Tutorial weblink, first example: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-chart-js-2-0-six-examples/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Weather Update</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function dspChrt() {

            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'apples',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                    }, {
                        label: 'oranges',
                        data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


</head>


<body onload="dspChrt();">

    <div class="container">

        <h2>Chart Demo</h2>

        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as per your code we can see you have not included chart.js file

Comment: I included, sorry missed in editing the code. I updated the code in OP.

Comment: Copying your code into a file and loading in a web browser presents me with a nice 2-series filled line chart. The problem doesn't appear to be with your code.

Comment: You are right, thank you for help. I run the code at another computer and it is displaying the chart. Seems connection to network is blocked on my workstation so charts js is not loaded. I need to contact network administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Use this code**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var data = {
     labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'apples',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
    }, {
      label: 'oranges',
      data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
    }]
};
var option = {
 scales: {
   yAxes:[{
      stacked:true,
        gridLines: {
         display:true,
          color:"rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
        }
    }],
    xAxes:[{
      gridLines: {
         display:true
        }
    }]
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
 data:data,
  options:option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">

  <h2>Chart Demo</h2>

  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"  width="400" height="200"></canvas>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: can you please guide main how to arrange this code in an html file. Like I put the js code in a function inside a script, called the charts.js inside header.  ecause your code is not in a full html that's why I am finding it difficult to arrange components inside an html file.

Comment: add another .js file and add the above js contents, then place the .js file below the charts.js file.

Comment: you mean an external js file ?

Comment: no create your own js file (eg: test.js)and include the script

Comment: I did exactly that. Declared a js file chart.js but it's raising 2 errors. @ 1st line:'Document' is not defined. and @line 32: 'myBarChart' is assigned a value but never used.

Comment: When running your solution the plotted line graphs are displayed as stacked, although the points are not plotted correctly. Does anyone know why that's happening?

Comment: So I found this directly from Chart.js ... https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html  -----   "Stacked area charts can be used to show how one data trend is made up of a number of smaller pieces."   ---- I guess I answered my own question.